# Links to my page does not work

Tags: github, html, x-frame-options

I have a personal website and linked my github account and linkedin on it. The links are working fine locally. After I uploaded to my github(since I hosted it on my github), the links doesnt work and the errors are:

```
Refused to display 'https://github.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Comment: Let's show your source code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various solutions in "[Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6666423/6309)".

Adding a `target='_top'` or `target='_parent'` attribute to your link (`<a href="...">mylink</a>`) should be enough to ensure they never try to open in the current iframe your page might be in.